# Missing window list on bottom panel in gnome-classic

Tags: 11.10, gnome-classic

I am running Ubuntu 11.10 with Gnome Classic, and I got one more problem with the display.

When I launch programs, the corresponding icons are not on the bottom panel anymore...

How can I solve this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

You will need to use one of the shown panel-applets.

Press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> and right-click the bottom panel bar - N.B. <kbd>Win</kbd> is the Windows Symbol key

(If you are using Gnome Classic (No Effects) i.e. *gnome fallback mode* then to add to the panel use <kbd>Alt</kbd> and right-click)

Lots more information and some very useful links to customise your classic desktop can be found in the linked question.

---

1. [How to revert to GNOME Classic Desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58172/how-to-revert-to-gnome-classic)