# GNOME Bottom pannel missing (Ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: gnome

Here is how it appears:

[image: Here is how it appears]

It disappeared after I responded to "yes" to a message that told me something about removing a non working file, but to be honest I didn't read that well and just said yes :c
I hope I'll get some help

Comment: Did you mean Windows List gone missing? If yes, please try https://askubuntu.com/questions/99932/missing-window-list-on-bottom-panel-in-gnome-classic

Answer (score 1):

Try to completely reinstall GNOME, just open open the Terminal and run:

```
sudo apt-get remove ubuntu-gnome-desktop
sudo apt-get remove gnome-shell
sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove ubuntu-gnome-desktop
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove ubuntu-gnome-desktop
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-gnome-desktop
```

then `reboot`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to reinstall the GNOME desktop packages. Login to Unity (or to another desktop environment of your choice like KDE or press `Ctrl-Alt-F1` to go to the `tty1` session which is a CLI/Command Line Interface) , open a Terminal window (or go to `tty1` as I said above) and run this command:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall gnome
```

Since the GNOME Panel files are corrupted, you need to reinstall the GNOME packages because you don't know what files are corrupted. So, a reinstallation is recommended.

Hope this helps. If you need more, feel free to contact me.